# MDX parameter drop down not working in Sharepoint inegrated mode

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, reporting-services, mdx

Hi I have an MDX report there is a parameter and every time a user sets up a subscription, the next day after the cube build this parameter is causing the subscription to fail.  The error that I see is 'The subscription contains parameter values that are not valid.'  Im not sure why this is happening.  Any clues as to where I should look.  Ive already been checking the [subscriptions] table in the SSRS database and that seems to be fine
Thanks